# While converting char2num I am getting AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.api._v1.keras.layers' has no attribute 'experimental'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using `TensorFlow` to convert the char of a string into the numbers. Below is the function:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
char_to_num = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup(
vocabulary=list(characters), num_oov_indices=0, mask_token=None)
```

But I get the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.api._v1.keras.layers'
> has no attribute 'experimental'

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Can you add the TensorFlow version as well as complete error traceback?

Answer (score 1):

In Tensorflow 2.6.0 replace `tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup` by

```
tf.keras.layers.StringLookup
```

**Working sample code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
vocab = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
data = tf.constant([["a", "c", "d"], ["d", "z", "b"]])
layer = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab)
layer(data)
```

**Output**

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[1, 3, 4],
       [4, 0, 2]])>
```